# Angular Nested ngFor can't bind since it isn't a know property

Tags: angular, ngfor

I appreciate this is a well discussed topic, however I cannot seem to find a solution despite extensive reading on related questions.

In my case, **I'm simply trying to loop through a nested array of objects and display them in my Angular application**. My requirement is almost identical to this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4rq4mf?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

The issue I have is that when I attempt to perform a nested `*ngFor` loop, it get the following error:

> Can't bind to 'ngForFor' since it isn't a known property of 'li'. `("<h4>Staff</h4><ul><li [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let staff for futureBooking.users">{{ staff.name }}</li></ul></div>")`

### The template

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let futureBooking of futureBookings">
    <h3>{{futureBooking.classes_covered}}</h3>
    <div *ngIf="futureBooking.users.length">
      <h4>Staff</h4>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let staff for futureBooking.users">{{ staff.name }}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

### BookingsPage class (extract):

```
futureBookings = [];
private getFutureRequests() {
  this.booking.getFuture().subscribe(bookings => { 
    this.futureBookings = bookings;
  });
  return this.futureBookings;
}
```

### The JSON for futureBookings (extract):

[image]

### Additional information

There is no issue with the initial `*ngFor` loop. I can access details without issue. In fact if I do a direct reference to the sub-array data (e.g. `{{ futureBooking.users[0].name }}`) I can access it without issue.

I'm very new to Angular but familiar with JS so this is rather confusing to me. I wondered if this is a data access issue, but as the `futureBooking` variable is accessible and the `users` parameter is a child of this array's items, I'm lost.

Comment: Voting to close for typo. The syntax is `*ngFor="let element of array"`. Not `*ngFor="let element for array"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngFor in the nested loop needs to be ngFor **of** not **for** think there is a typo there

try change this line

`<li *ngFor="let staff for futureBooking.users">{{ staff.name }}</li>`

to this

`<li *ngFor="let staff of futureBooking.users">{{ staff.name }}</li>`

Comment: OMG... really?! Is that is in the documentation somewhere? I must have totally missed it. Massive facepalm moment. Thank you so much.

Comment: Sorry misunderstood to begin with... thought you meant a nested was "of" and the parent was "for"... I now follow that I'm just a tool. Thanks again.